# Within a Chrome Extension how do you add an event listener for a URL when part of the URL is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I am looking to activate a script when a page with a specific URL pattern is found but I am not sure the right syntax to match on any variation of the URL. For example I would want to match on any of the three page url examples:

- https://www.mywebsite.com/people/person1/profile
- https://www.mywebsite.com/people/person2/profile
- https://www.mywebsite.com/people/person3/profile

The code I have attempted in my background JS to accomplish this is:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.url == 'https://www.mywebsite.com/people/*/profile')
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: './helloworld.js'}, ()=> console.log('Activated for : ' + details.url));
    }
});
```

My issues is how to replace the star with something that allows me to match all of these dynamically but I am not certain what the right syntax would be.

Answer (score 1):

1. [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) API supports [event filters](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/events/#type-UrlFilter) so the listener will run only for the matching URLs.
2. `executeScript` should be used with tabId and frameId of the event's [details](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onCompleted) parameter because navigation can occur in inactive (backgrounded) tabs or in iframes.

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(details => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
    file: 'helloworld.js',
    frameId: details.frameId,
  });
}, {
  url: [{
    urlPrefix: 'https://www.mywebsite.com/people/',
    pathSuffix: '/profile',
  }],
});
```